# What is the past form of "ought to"?

Tags: past-tense, semi-modals

> I **ought to** help him .
>
> I **ought to have helped** him.

Shall I use (have + past participle) for the past  form of ***ought to***?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Ought to" is a modal verb. Modal verbs have only one form. They have no -ing or -ed forms. Modal verbs are followed by the infinitive of another verb without to. The exceptions are ought to, have to and used to: You must find a job. You ought to stop smoking.

Questions are formed without do/does in the present, or did in the past.    Negative sentences are formed with not or the short form -n’t and do not use do/does or did.

In case of "ought to" form the past by using "ought to have". For example: You ought to have been more careful.

Comment: But "I ought to have helped him" is not a full counterpart of "I ought to help him", because the present-tense form allows for the possibility that I *will* help him, while the *ought to have* form indicades that I did not. If we say "I was under an obligation to help him", this will leave open the possibility that I did in fact help him.

Comment: *I ought to help him* is the right thing to do, we are clear about that, but *I ought to have helped him* shows that I didn't do the right thing but did the wrong. It works for the past but not in the right way.

Comment: "ought to" already implies that you aren't currently helping, and can only begin to in the (possibly very near) future.

Answer (score 0):

"Ought to" is a semi-modal, I would say. Modal verbs (can, shall, may) have very clear past tense forms (could, should, might). "Ought to" is not nearly as clear.

I would expect "ought to" to be considered a past tense form that, like "must," has no present tense form. My reasoning is that "ought to" has the same meaning as "should," which is a past tense form. Experts (who clearly know more than I do, as linguistics is pretty far out of my area!) tend to take an opposing view and consider "ought to" to be a present-tense form. http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00138388408598359?journalCode=nest20